# Data tables css issue?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've been working on site using bootstrap. Rather than calling the unedited `bootstrap.css` and creating a seperate `.css` file for customisation I added my css changes directly to the `bootstrap.css`.

My question is - will this cause problems when it comes to using datatables?

Comment: Short answer; no. But I wouldn't recommend changes directly in the bootstrap.css. Just go with the custom css and make sure you load the bootstrap.css before your custom css

Answer (score 0):

Not necesserily. Depends on which classes are used in datatables. You either search in the source of datatables which classes are used or , what i recommend, make your own css, include it after the bootstrap css and change only what you need. For example with the !important markup.